# How to set background color on inner table only

Tags: html, css

Let's say that is my html code:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>A</td>
                     <td>B</td>
                     <td>C</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>D</td>
                     <td>E</td>
                     <td>F</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to paint only the inner table (A,B,C,D,E,F) to red (background-color:red)

**Important to note - there is no "class" or "id" on purpose!!! I want a solution without it...**

Answer (score 1):

```css
table table td {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>A</td>
                     <td>B</td>
                     <td>C</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>D</td>
                     <td>E</td>
                     <td>F</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

this selector basically means: table inside table

```css
table table{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>A</td>
                     <td>B</td>
                     <td>C</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>D</td>
                     <td>E</td>
                     <td>F</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `table table { ... }`. That should apply only to tables nested within another table tag. Or explicitely `table > tbody > tr > td > table { ... }`.

Hope this helps,

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Use selector like:

```
table table {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Translation: table inside table.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I misunderstood how to use the nth-child() psudeo-class. I understand it now. the below code will do what you ask.

To get the inner table you need to access the inner table rows. There are in fact other ways to do this using the nth formula however this is the simplest I can think of.

`3` translates to the 3rd table row inside the initial table tag.

```
table tr:nth-child(3){
    background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/USERALPHA32/ufjqgewa/1/

And this will also do what you ask. The difference between this fiddle and the one above is that this one will access the nested table directly https://jsfiddle.net/USERALPHA32/ufjqgewa/3/

```
table tr table:nth-child(1){
    background: red;
}
```

**__________________________ABOVE IS CORRECT__________________________________**

**__________________________BELOW IS WRONG____________________________________**

to get to a table inside a table you would do:

```
table:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

I believe you could use the nth-child selector. Though this may cause issue with cross browser support.

https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/nth-childn-css-selector/

Comment: This is really not helpful.

Comment: no mate, `nth-child` is used for nth sibling, even if we see two tables, still the inner table is first child inside its first parent table cell `td`.

Comment: my fault. understood.

Comment: @skobaljic I corrected my mistake and learned something too. Next time I won't be so hasty to come up with an answer without being 100% sure of it.

Comment: Still it would add background color to 3rd table row, not to table itself. You should target the nested table, as you can see in other answers. Your css selector won't target other nested table, as you can see in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufjqgewa/2/). Cheers

Comment: fair enough. https://jsfiddle.net/USERALPHA32/ufjqgewa/3/ that'll get nested tables.